# which supplements to go for?

Tags: supplements

Im from South Africa and here we don't have that much wider selection of supplements and I've been looking for one that works.

here we have USN (Ultimate Sports Nutrition) and by far it is the ultimate one in South Africa but I did research and most reviews aren't good and everyone on those boards is suggesting NPL and Optimum but Optimum it's not cheap and NPL isn't that good I tried it and saw no results.

So anyone that knows of a working and pocket friendly supplements that's available around here please tell me.

and I want supplements that will help me get lean muscles mass and I've been going for 100% protein shakes.

I've been lifting for 4 months now and when I started I was 52kg and now 4months later i'm 60,22Kg

Comment: As it stands, this is not on topic for the site. This is a product recommendation for a nutrition product, and has no relation to a fitness program. Merely saying "I work out, which supplement?" does not make it on topic.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, supplements are not mandatory. They can help if you don't have the time to cook/eat, *they are substitue to food, not magic to grown muscles*.

So before take supplements (which are pricy, etc..) asks you these
   questions:

- how many proteins do you take everyday ? Around 1.5/2g per kg is
  enough
- how many many meals do you take ? If you can eat 3-4 times a day, with at less 2 meals with proteins, more is not mandatory.
- your diet is composed of what ? If you eat a lot of junk food, start by replace often as possible with healhty food.

They are supplements which are more beneficial for grow muscles than proteins if you have already around 1.5/2g per kg, for example :

- creatine : can help to gain strengh in low rep 6-15. They give to you more energy in short exercice (30s - 1 min). And gain strengh will help to grow.
- omega 3 : they help in so many differents situations, feel free to consulte doc on the subject.
- vitamins : better health lead to better muscle grow